# Shifting array and add duplicate of previous value

Tags: c#, arrays

In my code I have string array of 1000 indexes and it contain unique string data. Now, I want to make duplicate of some of them string element without overwriting next element. To summarize I would like to shift the array and inserting a duplicate value.

Here my code is,

```
for (int r = 0; r < sResultarray1.Length; r++)
{
    if (sResultarray1[r] != null && 
        sResultarray1[r].Contains("WP") && 
        sResultarray1[r].Contains("CB") == true)
    {

        index = Array.IndexOf(sResultarray1, sResultarray1[r]);

        for (int e = 1000; e >= index + c; e--)
        {
            sResultarray1[e] = sResultarray1[e - c];
        }

        break;
     }
}
```

My current output is

```
++ST110+WP001.CB001
++ST120+WP001.CB001
++ST120+WP002.CB001
++ST130+WP001.CB001
++ST110+WP001.CB001
++ST120+WP001.CB001
++ST120+WP002.CB001
++ST130+WP001.CB001
```

My desired output is

```
++ST110+WP001.CB001
++ST110+WP001.CB001
++ST120+WP001.CB001
++ST120+WP001.CB001
++ST120+WP002.CB001
++ST120+WP002.CB001
++ST130+WP001.CB001
++ST130+WP001.CB001
```

Does anyone help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: When `Add`ing, `Insert`ing array (`string[]`) is not a good collection to work with. Try using `List<string>`

Comment: It would be better if your example outputs used strings that were more different, because right now it is more like the "find 5 errors" game.

Comment: Please, provide the *initial array* as well as actual an desired result.

Comment: Another option would be to have a collection of strings and counts, then duplicating becomes incrementing the counter and you don't have to change the collection.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *different collection type* - `List<string>` instead of `String[]` (at least temporarily): `Add`, `Insert` ("shift and add") are not operations array has been designed for. Something like this:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // Temporal collection - list
  List<string> list = sResultarray1.ToList();

  // Downward - we don't want to check the inserted item
  for (int r = list.Count - 1; r >= 0; --r) {
    if (list[r] != null && list[r].Contains("WP") && list[r].Contains("CB")) {
      // if you want to insert - "shift and add duplicate value" - just insert
      list.Insert(r + 1, list[r]);
    }
  }

  // back to the array
  sResultarray1 = list.ToArray();
```